# Error after login with login_check

Tags: symfony, authentication

I use the symfony2.3 LTS Version in one of my project. After i install the bundle "jms/serializer-bundle" and make an "composer update", i have the following problem.

1. I submit the login form with valid username and password
2. Login successfull
3. Logout "http://app.local/app_dev.php/logout"
4. Logout successfull

Now i try this steps a second time i get the following error message.

No route found for "POST //login_check"

My url on the browser is "http://app.local/app_dev.php//login_check"

But I can not assign why this happens, because i'm using the steps from the official documentation of Symfony in Version 2.3

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html

Comment: did you clear your cache?

Comment: I delete the content from the folders 'app/cache/dev' and 'app/cache/prod'. After i log out the url in Browser look like this "http://app.local/app_dev.php/" and i think the trailing slash is the problem, but i do not know how can i fix this